# How to debug app without uninstall release app

Tags: android, debugging, release

Is there a way to debug my app on my smartphone without uninstall the play Store release? 
I want to use my app, but the debug should not edit the preferences. 
I would like to use two different apps. 
Naturally without changing a lot of code each time I want to export as release apk.

Am I asking too much?

Comment: if it is not tied to devices then just debug it on emulator

Comment: The emulator is too slow...

Comment: Checkout HAXM if you are on an Intel based PC

Comment: @Simon thank you but the emulator remains too slow. I can't wait 15 minutes every time I start it. It is faster, but still slow. Apple is light years ahead

Comment: @fran  As usual, no they're not.  They just don't have to emulate.  Not sure what you're doing, but my HAXM based emulator starts in about 30 seconds and runs at about 75% speed of my S3.  Fine for most stuff.  Have you examined the log?

Comment: OMG!!! There is something wrong in my emulator. It runs on a MacBook "late 2009". I've installed HAXM but nothing is changed. I'll try to check if I've forgotten something. Thanks

Comment: @fran Did you figure out the answer for this question ?

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy Yes. I added the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is changing the `applicationId` in the app `build.gradle` file as suggested by the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id):

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you could do is change the package name in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

The preferences would not be the only problem to face: You also won't be able to install the debug version over the release version due to the different certificates.